# Changed to options listed in PyQt4 combo_boxes defined in a different class not reflected

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am working on a small GUI project using PyQt4. I have defined one class (inside a separate file) defining the basic functionality of combo_boxes that I have to use and another class to use the functionality for all the combo_boxes. 
The code looks something like

```
class core:
    def __init__(self, default_value, window_name):
        self.combo_box = QtGui.QComboBox(window_name)
        self.combo_box.addItem(default_value)
        self.combo_box.addItem("some other value")
        self.combo_box.addItem("a third value")
        self.combo_box.activated[str].connect(self.set_text)
        self.text = default_value


    def set_text(self, text):
        print text
```

The main class is something like:

```
from file import *
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(200, 100, 820, 700)
        combo_box_one = core("first", self)
        combo_box_two = core("second", self)

     #some other methods follow defining the geometry for each combo_box and other functions

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
main()
```

The GUI is working as expected. All the combo_boxes appear as per the defined geometry. However, when on selecting different options, nothing seems to happen. Ideally, I would expect the text on the option to be printed. In fact, when I return the combo_box object to the main class and set it connections there, the change in options is reflected. But when the same thing is done in the `core`class, the changes are not reflected as printed text. Is it a scope related thing? Please help me understand what's happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slots can only be implemented in classes that inherit from `QObject`, a simple solution is that the core class inherits from `QComboBox`, since `QComboBox` inherits from `QObject`.

```
class core(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, default_value, window_name):
        QtGui.QComboBox.__init__(self, window_name)
        self.addItem(default_value)
        self.addItem("some other value")
        self.addItem("a third value")
        self.activated[str].connect(self.set_text)


    def set_text(self, text):
        print(text)
```

Comment: @eyllansec thanks for the comment. This helps in printing the text. I figured that would solve the problem. But if I set a text variable in the `core` class as  `self.text = text` in the `set_text` method, 
and try to call this from the main class everytime I push a button, the default value of the `self.text` variable. I am not sure why. I was under the impression that everytime the button is pushed, the present value would be returned.